# VBA command CopyDatabaseFile hits Run-time error '2046'

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to use the CopyDatabaseFile command in a VBA subroutine or function;  e.g., "DoCmd.CopyDatabaseFile , true, true".  The code compiles okay, but hits "Run-time Error '2046'" whenever I try to execute it.  What's my problem? Does this on a network or running on a standalone PC, in Access 2010 and 2016, all in Win10?

Have tried it in the accdb I want to backup on a network drive.  Have tried it on a standalone PC copying to the C: drive.  Have tried it in a new accdb in which it is the only code.  Have tried it in Access 2010 and 2016 all on Win10.  Have tried it after rebooting PC in all those situations.

```vb
Public Sub cmdBackupDB()

    Dim strBackupDB As String

    strBackupDB = "C:\DBDIR\NewFileName"

    DoCmd.CopyDatabaseFile strBackupDB, True, True

End Sub
```

I expect it to copy the current database accdb file/project to the new filename.

Here's what I get:

Microsoft Visual Basic
Run-time error '2016':
The command or action 'CopyDatabaseFile' isn't available now.

Comment: If you had read the help file (press F1 while cursor is on method name) of [DoCmd.CopyDatabaseFile](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/copydatabasefile-macro-action-63153203-d3ee-4309-b598-e4626f5f0131) you would know it is for .ADP databases. Unfortunally those are deprecated since Office 2007 (because they provided direct ADO connection to SQL-Server):

Comment: [Backup](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/protect-your-data-with-backup-and-restore-processes-96539a81-5984-4d56-99ca-ee81f8d6356c) is one of the biggest disadvantages of a MS-Access Backend, because you have to open in exclusive mode, what means no one can use it at that time!